# Pause loading elements until previous one finishes in list view

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and am trying to make an app with an infinite list view that loads images from the network using a Future builder for each image. The problem is that the list view loads a lot of future builders at once and this creates a lot of lag on slower devices. So, is there ant way to pause the rendering and add the new Future builder only when the build function of the previous one has returned?

Edit:
Async/Await on builder function does not work and results in the following error.
(the code works fine without the "async" in the builder method of FutureBuilder)

The code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyyApp());

class MyyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Cats!",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: Catshomepage(title: "Cats!"),
    );
  }
}

class Catshomepage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  Catshomepage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CatshomepageState createState() => _CatshomepageState();
}

class _CatshomepageState extends State<Catshomepage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  fetchAlbum() async {
    var rresponse = http.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search');

    var joon;
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonoutput;

    await rresponse
        .then(
            (value) => {joon = value.body.substring(1, value.body.length - 1)})
        .then((value) {
      jsonoutput = jsonDecode(joon);
    });

    var finalval = jsonoutput['url'];

    url = finalval;

    // setState(() {});

    return finalval;
  }

  savephoto(inpurl) {
    if (inpurl.isNotEmpty) {
      GallerySaver.saveImage(inpurl, albumName: 'Media').then((value) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Image Saved!"),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        ));
      }).catchError((error) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Error! Can not save image."),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        ));
      });
    }
  }

  var url;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureing;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            futureing = fetchAlbum();
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: imgrenderer(futureing, _scaffoldKey, savephoto),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget imgrenderer(incomingfuture, scaffolddkeyinp, savephoto) {
  return Center(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder(
          future: incomingfuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) async {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                scaffolddkeyinp.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Error!"),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                ));
              } else {
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          child: Image.network(
                            snapshot.data,
                            loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                                ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                              return Center(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                  ),
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            // "https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x3000",
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          // setState(() {});
                        },
                      ),
                      // shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        savephoto(snapshot.data);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }
            return SizedBox(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:103:20: Error: The argument type 'Future<RenderObjectWidget> Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'RenderObjectWidget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../FFlutter/flutterr_files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../FFlutter/flutterr_files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'AsyncSnapshot' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart' ('../../../FFlutter/flutterr_files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart').        
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../FFlutter/flutterr_files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').       
          builder: (context, snapshot) async {
```

Comment: why not use await with async?

Comment: @Maz341 I tried to put async to the build function but it gives the error "The argument type 'Future<RenderObjectWidget> Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)'"

Comment: how about posting code with error?

Comment: @Maz341 Added the full code and the error as well...